# How can schedule an event that doesn't start on 00, 15, 30, or 45 on Microsoft Outlook for Android?

Tags: outlook

How can schedule an event that doesn't start on 00, 15, 30, or 45 on Microsoft Outlook for Android?

For example, I would like to schedule an event that starts at 14:08, but when I drag and drop the event, the start is always on 00, 15, 30, or 45:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your screenshot, the top row of "choose time" go to the far right. You will see up and down arrows with 00:00 in between. Select that and you then will be able to enter a specific time.